# Difference between PermissionsAndroid.request and PermissionsAndroid.check

Tags: react-native

I am new to react-native am trying to understand how to get runtime permission.I wanted to know what is the difference between PermissionsAndroid.request and PermissionsAndroid.check and when to use request and when to use check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PermissionsAndroid.check

> Returns a promise resolving to a boolean value as to whether the specified permissions has been granted.

PermissionsAndroid.request

> Prompts the user to enable a permission and returns a promise resolving to a string value indicating whether the user allowed or denied the request or does not want to be asked again.

so first you have to check if specific permission is granted, and then if not granted request for permission and the continue with the flow.

[source](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid)

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests:

```
`PermissionsAndroid.check

Returns a promise resolving to a boolean value as to whether the specified permissions has been granted`.

`PermissionsAndroid.request

Prompts the user to enable a permission and returns a promise resolving to a string value indicating whether the user allowed or denied the request or does not want to be asked again.`
```